# checking paragraph property loses the selection

Tags: ms-word, vsto, selection

in my vsto addin i have some simple code on a timer

```
private void MainTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!dialogopen & Application.Documents.Count > 0)
        {
            var doc = Application.ActiveDocument;
            Word.InlineShapes shps;
            Word.Paragraphs pars;
            try
            {
                pars = doc.Paragraphs;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return;
            }
            var pars2 = pars.Cast<Word.Paragraph>().ToList();
            foreach (var obj in pars2)
            {
                if (obj.OutlineLevel == Word.WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText )//PROBLEM HERE
                {

                };
            }

        }
    }
```

as soon as it reaches the line that checks the outlinelevel, even if i dont do a thing, the selection in the activedocument gets lost

of course the user cant use a plugin which keeps on canceling his selection...

googling didnt give me a thing

thanks

**EDIT1**

I tried making a `static` function for checking the styles, but it did not help. Here's the code

```
static public class Helpers
{
    static public Word.Paragraph checkPars(List<Word.Paragraph> pars)
    {
        return pars.FirstOrDefault();//(x) => x.OutlineLevel == Word.WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I had to remove the actual check, since it was causing the cursor to blink and lose selection

please advise

Comment: Show some more code. How do you initialise and load `pars`?

Comment: hi. i just pust as much code as i can under my NDA...

Comment: Have you tried making it a static class and passing the context you need via the sender and/or the event args?  May be a good idea to avoid accessing the `Application.ActiveDocument`.  You could sub-class `System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs` to get the accessors and state that you need.  You could even pass the UI Dispatch object in and put it on a different thread.

Comment: The other thing you might check is if the selection is actually lost. It could be a screen updating issue that could be (kind of) solved with zoom out/in or a `Application.ScreenRefresh`.

Comment: Passing the pars to a static function helped not, how can i avoid using `ActiveDocument`? how else can i (originally) access the paragraphs? Thanks!

Comment: If you already have a reference to the document in the event source declaration context then pass that on the event args. Don't acquire a new reference in the hander and don't reference ActiveDocument in the handler. There are many layers of abstraction to get that: VSTO, PIA and then abstractions in word. Did you check if the selection is really gone? Like I suggested in my second comment?

Comment: Hi. Adding `Application.ScreenRefresh`, makes the selection keep. but its still blinking terribly,which is very distorting. I'm not sure what you mean by 'already have a reference'. Where? I can't seem to find any other way to get a hang of the current doc. Can you maybe link/post some sample code? Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I'm sure you could figure out a way to get a reference when the doc is opened but anyway, it doesn't matter.  I tried doing it with a reference to the doc taken before the selection was made and use that instead of `ActiveDocument` and it didn't make any difference: the selection still disappeared from the UI. However, I did find a way to fix it that worked for me.  Please let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the `Application.ScreenUpdating = true;` and this keep the selection for all properties in `Paragraph` except for the `Range` property.

Then, we tried to access the range via Reflection and this was the solution.

```
Range rng = (Range)typeof(Paragraph).GetProperty("Range").GetValue(comObj);
```

Comment: oh wow! thats a cool idea. works great! thanks! would never have thought of it myself...

Answer (score 1):

We tried to eliminate querying `ActiveDocument` thinking that that might have had side-effects that were causing the problem but that was not the case.

Then, we confirmed that the selection was not "lost" and screen-updating is the only problem, so we tried restoring the UI with `Application.ScreenRefresh` and while it did work, it causes the screen to flicker every time the timer fires and this is not good enough.

Finally, knowing that it's only a UI problem, I tried simply switching off `Application.ScreenUpdating`...

in `ThisAddin`

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(2000);
    timer.Elapsed += (s, t) =>
    {
        var scrnUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating;
        Application.ScreenUpdating = false;

        MainTimer.onElapsed(Application, t);

        if (scrnUpdating)
            Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

In another class library (note that it's static, I still think this is the best way)...

```
public static class MainTimer
{
    public static void onElapsed (Word.Application state, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (state.Documents.Count > 0)
        {
            var doc = state.ActiveDocument;
            Word.InlineShapes shps;
            Word.Paragraphs pars;
            try
            {
                pars = doc.Paragraphs;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return;
            }
            var pars2 = pars.Cast<Word.Paragraph>()
                .Where(p => p.OutlineLevel == Word.WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText)
                .Select(p => p) // do stuff with the selected parragraphs...
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

And this works for me.
The selection remains and is displayed in the UI without flicker.

I also eliminated some premature enumeration from your code: you don't meed the `.ToList()` before the `foreach`.

Comment: thanks. your code works. i dont quite get how the static code does the trick but it works. also, i think the UI is still a bit quirky, but for the MVP its ok meanwhile. gracias!

Comment: The static code is just my (disposable) view of best practice *but* not relevant to the solution. The _*fix*_ is to turn off 'Application.ScreenUpdating'. This seems to be the key.  And... de nada.

Comment: Why do you think the UI is still a bit quirky? Is it still flickering for you?

Comment: im not sure. it seems that the mouse is not very responsive, sometimes it takes like a few clicks till something gets selected. its still very early in test stage, but i believe my user will complain shortly...

Comment: @YisroelM.Olewski Well, its not really a recommended approach to be synchronously polling your documents like this and if you have a significant nymber of paragraphs then, even if you pass them to a background thread, you will stil have a quirky UI.  If you must do this then I imagine you would have to index the parragraphs somehow and check for changes before spending time processing.

Comment: Hi. I would love to have some event or notification that a paragraph has been changed or added, but I cannot seem to find anything like that. What IS the recommended approach for reacting to changes in a document? (BTW `Select All` currently does not work when the add-in is active)

Comment: Yes, I even tried it with another thread but even for a medium-sized doc, it just spends too much time with screenupdating off so, as you say, quirky. Funny you should mention the word [react](https://github.com/reactjs). Obviously it JS, but the principle of some kind of virtual document might be what you have to do.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by a virtual document?